# Tkinter get() doesn't return a value

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def updatehw():
   markIntHw = tkinter.DoubleVar()
   dateSrtHw = tkinter.StringVar()

   mark = ttk.Entry(englishGraphsRoot, textvariable=markIntHw, text="Mark")
   dat = ttk.Entry(englishGraphsRoot, textvariable=dateSrtHw, text="Date")

   def getr():
      xv = markIntHw.get()
      xt = dateSrtHw.get()
      cursor.execute('INSERT INTO graph_englishhw(xticks, xvalues) VALUES(?, ?)', (xt, xv))
      connection.commit()
      mark.destroy()
      dat.destroy()
      buttonUpdateHw.destroy()

   buttonUpdateHw = ttk.Button(command=getr, text="Submit")
   buttonUpdateHw.pack()
```

Except xt & xv don't get the values inputted but instead 0.0 and None are added to the table.

Comment: Can you post your complete code? by the way, are `markIntHw` and `dateSrtHw` global?

Comment: I have already solved it, apparently, there isn't such a 'text' attribute to an Entry widget. Thank you for your time though.